# Huawei USB dongle is not working in Newly installed Arch Linux with Gnome

Tags: arch-linux, networkmanager

At the Arch Linux installation, I installed `dialog` & `wpa_supplicant` in order to connect to the internet after the rebooting to the newly installed system  via `wifi-menu` program. After that, installed `gnome` , `gnoem-extra`, `networkmanager`, `network-manager-applet`. Started service of network manager

```
sudo systemctl enable NetworkManager.service
sudo systemctl start NetworkManager.service
```

Network Manager works fine with WiFi network (shows the icon says "WiFi", and under that all the wifi devices). The problem is Huawei USB dongle is not working. When it  is pluged in, Arch mount the device. `lsblk` print the device as `/dev/sr1`. But nothing shows in the right corner drop menu. This dongle is worked with Ubuntu, Linux Mint, Even in Arch(previous installation).

Answer (score 0):

Read the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/USB_3G_Modem).

Have you installed `usb_modeswitch`, `usbutils` and `modemmanager`? What is the vendor ID and the product ID of your Huawei USB modem? Find them with `$ lsusb` and edit your `/lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules` file to add the vendor ID and the product ID. You may need to restart your computer after doing this.